# Объявление переменных в GO, Golang

Tags: golang, variable

```
$ cat function_e.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func plus(a int, b int) int {
    var c int
    var c = a + b
    return c
}

func main() {
    summ := plus(1, 2)
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", summ)
}

$ go run function_e.go 
# command-line-arguments
./function_e.go:9:6: c redeclared in this block
    previous declaration at ./function_e.go:8:6
```

Почему возникает ошибка при объявлении переменной "c" в строке?

```
var c int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда перед именем переменной вы написали `var`, вы сделали объявление переменной. И в вашем коде, написав `var` дважды перед переменной `c` вы объявили её дважды, чего делать нельзя, и о чём вам сообщил компилятор.

Чтобы исправить ошибку удалите строку `var c int` с первым объявлением или удалите `var` перед вторым.